# Flaky pipeline on Jenkins with docker agents

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have several Jenkins agents running as physical machines.
So far I ran my Jenkins pipeline on the agents themselves, I now try to move the building and test execution into docker containers using the Jenins docker plugin.

Below you can find a simplified version of our Jenkinsfile which uses gradle to build, test, and package a Java Spring Boot application.

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
        notifyBitbucket()
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image "our-custom-registry.com/jenkins-build:latest"
            registryUrl 'https://our-custom-registry.com'
            registryCredentialsId '...'
            alwaysPull true
            args "-u jenkins -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" // the pipeline itself required docker
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew assemble classes testClasses'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage('Unit Tests') {
                    when { expression { return build_params.ENABLE_UNITTEST } }
                    steps {
                        sh './gradlew test'
                        junit UNIT_TEST_RESULT_DIR
                    }
                }

                stage('Integration Tests') {
                    when { expression { return build_params.ENABLE_INTEGRATION } }
                    steps {
                        sh './gradlew integration'
                        junit INTEGRATION_TEST_RESULT_DIR
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Finalize') {
            stage('Docker Push') {
                when { expression { return build_params.ENABLE_DOCKER_PUSH } }
                steps {
                    sh './gradlew pushDockerImage'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }
        always {
            script {
                node {
                    currentBuild.result = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
                    notifyBitbucket()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Dockerfile I use for the build image. As you can see I manually create a Jenkins user and add the to the docker groups (unfortunately the GID is 998 or 999 depending on the Jenkins agent).

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-stretch

USER root
# prerequisites:
# - a user and a group Jenkins with UID/GID=1001 exist
# - the user home is /var/jenkins
# - the user is in the docker group
# - on some agents docker has the gid 998, on some it is 999
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common rsync tree \
    && curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io \
    && groupadd -g 1001 jenkins \
    && groupadd -f -g 998 docker1 \
    && groupadd -f -g 999 docker2 \
    && useradd -d "/var/jenkins" -u 1001 -g 1001 -m -s /bin/bash jenkins \
    && usermod -a -G 998 jenkins \
    && usermod -a -G 999 jenkins

USER jenkins
```

Jenkins then executes the following command

```
docker run -t -d -u 1001:1001 -u jenkins -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -w /var/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME -v /var/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME:/var/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME:rw,z -v /var/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME@tmp:/var/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME@tmp:rw,z -e ******** ... our-custom-registry.com/base/jenkins-build:latest cat
```

This pipeline works just fine... sometimes!
Most of the times, however, some files get mysteriously lost.

For example, my `build.gradle` consists of multiple other files that are included.
At some point during the build, one of these files seems to be missing.

```
+ ./gradlew pushDockerImage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/****/workspace/JOB_NAME/build.gradle' line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'foo'.
> Could not read script '/var/****/workspace/JOB_NAME/build/gradle/scripts/springboot-plugin.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

It is always a different file that goes missing.

I started running `tree` just before the `./gradlew` just to make sure the file is not actually removed.

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on here?

## Update

Forget everything I said about docker, this is a pure Gradle and Jenkins problem.
When I replace the docker agent with a plain Jenkins agent the same problems occur.
The problem seems to be that you cannot run multiple gradle tasks in parallel on the same directory.